# How does one use REGEX in --grep in GIT reflog?

Tags: regex, git, grep

Suppose I'm trying to find the commit references of any commits prefixed with some designated branch names (`Feature-123`, `Feature-126` and `Feature-159`).  Why won't the following GIT command work?

`GIT reflog --grep 'Feature-1(59|2(3|6))'`

But yet without REGEX, these 3 individual commands work fine (return results).

```
GIT reflog --grep 'Feature-123'
GIT reflog --grep 'Feature-126'
GIT reflog --grep 'Feature-159'
```

Does `--grep` not support REGEX in this context in spite of standing for Global Regular Expression Print?

Comment: `git reflog  --grep 'Feature-1\(23\|26\|59\)'`

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon Ah you got it!  Post it as the answer and I'll accept.  Does all REGEX syntax have to be escaped like this in GREP?

Comment: Inside git grep you need to escape special character. If you do it with normal grep they're not necessary. `git reflog | grep -E 'Feature-1(23|26|59)'`. The `-E` tells grep it's a regex.

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon That way using `-E` with the `|` before `grep` and no `--` threw me a little at first.  I'm guessing it pipes the output of `reflog` into `grep` rather than it being part of the same command.

Comment: That is correct. The output of `reflog` is piped into the `grep` command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape out special characters.

`git reflog --grep 'Feature-1\(23\|26\|59\)'`

Comment: It's not *escaping*, it's a different syntax. It's [Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html). `git grep` like `grep` uses basic syntax by default. It can be changed to extended syntax with [`git grep -E`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--E), to fixed strings with `-F` and to perl-like with `-P`.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm you would not need to escape ( and |, when using git grep [`-E` (`--extended-regexp`, POSIX extended regexp for patterns)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--E) or [`-P` (`--perl-regexp`, Perl-compatible regular expressions for patterns)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--P)

But, if you were to use `-P`, make sure to use  Git 2.35 (Q1 2022).

"[`git grep --perl-regexp`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c91b0b7c7270dac8c539062d193749e654b7f002/Documentation/git-grep.txt#L135)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt---perl-regexp))</sup> failed to match UTF-8 characters with wildcard when the pattern consists only of ASCII letters, which has been corrected with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022).

You don't have special UTF-8 characters in your target strings, but others might.

See [commit 32e3e8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32e3e8bc551e7b10bbda07110ae7cb15442d0392), [commit dc2c44f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc2c44fbb100fa609174d9069a70e2b54b0591ca) (18 Dec 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c91b0b7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c91b0b7c7270dac8c539062d193749e654b7f002), 05 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`grep/pcre2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc2c44fbb100fa609174d9069a70e2b54b0591ca): use `PCRE2_UTF` even with ASCII patterns
>
> <sup>Original-patch-by: Hamza Mahfooz</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> `compile_pcre2_pattern()` currently uses the option `PCRE2_UTF` only for patterns with non-ASCII characters.
> Patterns with ASCII wildcards can match non-ASCII strings, though.
> Without that option PCRE2 mishandles UTF-8 input, though -- it matches parts of multi-byte characters.
> Fix that by using `PCRE2_UTF` even for ASCII-only patterns.
>
> This is a remake of the reverted [ae39ba4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae39ba431ab861548eb60b4bd2e1d8b8813db76f) ("`grep/pcre2`: fix an edge case concerning ascii patterns and UTF-8 data", 2021-10-15, Git v2.34.0-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b93d7206919e9eac22b3ca0291bce8da65960595)).